# Split por letras maiúsculas

Tags: ruby

Como eu posso usar o `split` para separar as palavras na frase `"QueroSepararAsPalavrasNestaSentença"` em Ruby?

Comment: já testaste `"QueroSepararAsPalavrasNestaSentença".split /(?=[A-Z])/`?

Comment: Ah, o problema aí parece ser a cedilha (`ç`), senão um `.split` funcionava bem: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/9b484

Comment: `"QueroSepararAsPalavrasNestaSentença".split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")` ?

Comment: Funcionou :D muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende muito de como está a frase que você quer separar. Se não há caracteres acentuados, basta usar o que já foi sugerido nos comentários:

```
"QueroSepararAsPalavrasNestaSentença".split /(?=[A-Z])/
```

Aqui é usado uma expressão regular (regex) contendo um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), denotado pela sintaxe `(?=`. Basicamente, o *lookahead* serve para verificar se algo existe à frente. No caso, estou usando a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z]`, que corresponde a uma letra de `A` a `Z`.

O "truque" do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica se existe uma letra maiúscula, mas esta não faz parte do *match*. O resultado disso é que a regex retorna apenas a posição da string que possui uma letra maiúscula à frente, e o [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#split-method) é feito nessa posição.

O resultado é que a string é quebrada nos pontos imediamente anteriores à uma letra maiúscula. No caso da string acima, o resultado é:

```
["Quero", "Separar", "As", "Palavras", "Nesta", "Sentença"]
```

Se a string for `ABCdeFG`, o resultado será `["A", "B", "Cde", "F", "G"]` - repare que a quebra é feita antes de cada uma das letra maiúsculas. Quando há mais de uma letra maiúscula seguida, cada uma delas se torna um elemento diferente do array.

---

#### Caracteres acentuados

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405558/112052) sugere usar `[A-ZÀ-Ú]`, que funciona em muitos casos, mas há alguns detalhes a se atentar.

O intervalo `À-Ú` pega várias letras maiúsculas com acento, mas também pega outros caracteres que não são necessariamente "letras", como o [MULTIPLICATION SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) (que é o caractere `×`, que dependendo da fonte usada, se parece muito com a letra `x` minúscula - e em algumas fontes pode até ser idêntico - mas é outro caractere, e está longe de ser uma letra maiúscula).

Além disso, este intervalo deixa de fora o `Û`, o `Ü` e o `Ý`. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/BxjjtP/2) um exemplo.
Obviamente que, se seu texto nunca tem os caracteres citados, isso não será um problema.

Mas se quiser uma opção mais "genérica" para aceitar quaisquer letras, use uma regex com propriedades Unicode:

```
sua_string.split /(?=\p{Lu})/
```

No caso, `\p{Lu}` considera qualquer caractere que esteja na categoria Unicode ["Letter, Uppercase"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm). Isso inclui caracteres de todos os alfabetos que estão mapeados pelo Unicode (não só o nosso alfabeto latino).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `split` com a seguinte expressão regular: `/(?=[A-ZÀ-Ú])/`. Vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```rb
expression = 'EssaÉUmaFraseÇÁrvore'

expression.split(/(?=[A-ZÀ-Ú])/)
=> ["Essa", "É", "Uma", "Frase", "Ç", "Árvore"]
```